# Scale and log transformation of a feature based on different measurements

Tags: regression, distributions

I have a dependent variable (price) which has been measured in two different currencies (currencies are unknown) and the plot looks like this:
[image]

Is it ok to log/scale them and handle them at once or should I separate them and build two OLS regression models for each of them?

Comment: What sort of model and regression procedure are you planning to use?   This is relevant as, for example, if you are using a tree-based regression model like a gradient boosting machine, monotonic transforms won't affect the results.

Comment: You can find historical daily exchange rate information at several places online, for example, https://ycharts.com/indicators/us_dollar_to_euro_exchange_rate.  Not sure how many / which are free, but I would assume there are some.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning. I edited my question. I'd like to run a simple OLS regression based on price but since there are two distinct distribution I'm not sure if I need to transform and scale them or should I separate them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is mostly no. And the reason is because of the context of the covariates being currencies. Your covariates are not on the same scale across data points.

Inflation rate fluctuates over time. \$10 today is different from \$10 ten years later. For some unstable countries, values change rapidly between days. The multi-modal distribution on the right can possibly be caused by heavy inflation/deflation periods.

My suggestion is to normalize all values to a specific date by adjusting for overall inflation in both country. Then maybe you can try log-transformation to get a more normal distribution.

But note that traditional OLS regression makes no assumption about feature being normal. Assumptions are made on the structure of error, not covariates. In practice, the transformation to normality usually helps with heteroscedasticity issue, but you should check if there is any heteroscedasticity before going through the transformation.

Comment: The OP observed that the bimodality was due to the price being measured in two different currencies,with an unknown exchange rate, not two different time periods after some substantial inflation.